# Isn't kernel ridge regression supposed to be the mean of gaussian processes?

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, kernel-smoothing

I read a few times that the mean prediction of a GP should be equivalent to KRR. I tested this empirically and found (dataset is y=2x + gaussian noise):
[image]

Two explanations for this come to mind:

- GP is bayesian, so trains using log marginal likelihood, which is sometimes called [bayesian's occam razor](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/occam.pdf). This would however contradict the common saying (KRR \= GP mean)
- GP can train its hyperparameters (lengthscale and variance) by gradient descent, whereas the sklearn code I'm using is only doing a gridsearch on krr's hyperparameters (can we can krr's hyperparameters --regularization term alpha and lengthscale-- by gradient descent?), which could make GP better empirically

Are these right? Or is there something else going on here?

```
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-10,10,.25)[:,None]
Y = 2*X + np.random.randn(X.shape[0],1)*5
plt.scatter(X,Y, c='green')

krbf = GPy.kern.RBF(1)
m = GPy.models.GPRegression(X,Y,krbf)
m.optimize()
plt.plot(X,m.predict(X)[0], label='gp')

kr = GridSearchCV(KernelRidge(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1), cv=5,
                  param_grid={"alpha": [1e0, 0.1, 1e-2, 1e-3],
                              "gamma": np.array([1,5,10,15,20])})
kr.fit(X,Y)
plt.plot(X,rr.predict(X), label='kr')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mean of the predictive distribution for GP regression is equal to the prediction using kernel ridge regression *when using the same kernel and hyperparameters*.

Suppose we have observed training inputs $X = \{x_1, \dots x_n\}$ with corresponding real-valued outputs $y = [y_1, \dots, y_n]^T$. We're interested in predicting the output for some new test input $x_*$. Assume the model:

$$y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$$

where the $\epsilon_i$ represent i.i.d. Gaussian noise with variance $\sigma_n^2$. Let $k$ be a kernel function (a.k.a. covariance function in the case of GP regression). Let $K$ denote the kernel matrix for the training points, so $K_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$. And, let vector $k_* = [k(x_*, x_1), \dots, k(x_*, x_n)]^T$ contain the result of evaluating the kernel function between the test input and each training input.

In **kernel ridge regression**, the predicted ouput at $x_*$ is:

$$\hat{y}_* = k_*^T (K + \lambda I)^{-1} y$$

where $\lambda$ is the regularization parameter and $I$ is the identity matrix.

In **GP regression** we have a Gaussian posterior predictive distribution over the output at $x_*$, with mean:

$$\bar{f}_* = k_*^T (K + \sigma_n^2 I)^{-1} y$$

where the noise variance $\sigma_n^2$ is considered a hyperparameter. See [Rasmussen and Williams ch2.2](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/) for details.

You can see that the predictions for kernel ridge regression and GP regression are equal, as long as $\lambda = \sigma_n^2$ and the same kernel function is used in both cases (including any hyperparameters).

In your example, GP regression and kernel ridge regression give different predictions because you're using fitting the hyperparameters separately for each, using different methods. You're using cross validation for kernel ridge regression. And, if I recall correctly, sklearn chooses GP regression hyperparameters by maximizing the marginal likelihood. So, you're probably ending up with different hyperparameters for each method.

Comment: Makes sense. Then I should fit GP with LOOCV since krr can't be trained by lml, which can be done by gradient descent. Can krr's hyperparameters be trained by gradient descent?

Comment: Also, GP doesn't have a hyperparameter equivalent to krr's lambda (regularization weight)... Is there an equivalence between this lambda and a combination of the GP's kernel's 2 hyperparameters (lengthscale and variance)??

Comment: @samlaf Each method selects hyperparameters by optimizing a different criterion. Using LOOCV or gradient descent for KRR will not make them the same because KRR simply has no analog of GPR's marginal likelihood. There is a correspondence between KRR's lambda and GPR's noise variance (in sklearn, this is implemented using the WhiteKernel).

Comment: I meant that while KRR can't be trained by marginal likelihood, GP can be trained by LOOCV, so we could make them "the same" by training both using LOOCV. I can't see the correspondence between KRR's lambda and GPR's noise variance. KRR's lambda would be equivalent to having a gaussian prior with lambda covariance on the weight in bayesian kernel linear regression. I'm not sure how or why this would translate to the noise model on y when we look at BKLR in the functional view (GP). Would you mind expanding your answer to include this?

Comment: @samlaf I see; yes, it's possible to tune hyperparameters to minimize validation set error in both cases. But, this may be slower than maximizing GPR marginal likelihood so one typically wouldn't choose to do that in practice. I edited the answer to include information about the noise variance. You can find much more detail in the book chapter I linked.

Comment: [This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_compare_gpr_krr.html) may be of interest

Comment: Amazing thank you! I still don't have a very good intuitive understanding for the relationship between KRR's lambda and GP's noise sigma, but at least I can believe it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, however in case it may be relevant to other readers - the reason why your Kernel Ridge Regression model has performed poorly is the range of values you have chosen for gamma. If you use the same range of values you have for alpha as the values for gamma, then you get pretty much the same result for both methods.

[image]